# For Loop to Find Matching Values and Total in Python

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project where my Manifests model consists of item codes and quantity. I want to loop through the model and find the total quantity for each item code. So I have the following in my view:

```
manifest = Manifests.objects.all()
```

How could I use a for loop or something to total the quantity for each item code.  Or more clearly, if item code 10 is there 3 times with quantities = 1, 2, and 3. Total should be 6 for item code 10, and if item code 20 is there twice with quantities = 2 and 5 total should be 7.

Here is the model for reference:

models.py

```
class Manifests(models.Model):
    reference = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    item_code = models.ForeignKey(Products, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please do *not* use `for` loops. You can annotate your queryset of `Products` with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Products.objects.annotate(
    total_quantity=Sum('manifests__quantity')
)
```

The `Products` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.total_quantity` that will contain the sum of the `.quantity`s of the *related* `Manifests`s objects.

Or you can count only the `Manifests` objects with `reference=10` with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Q

Products.objects.filter(
    Q(manifests=None) | Q(manifests__reference=10)
).annotate(
    total_quantity=Sum('manifests__quantity')
)
```

> **Note**: usually the name of a model is *singular*, so `Manifest` instead of <s>`Manifests`</s>, and `Product` instead of <s>`Products`</s>.

Comment: thank you for the advice on not using ```for``` loops - this worked perfeclty. Hopefully you can answer a follow up question - how could I extend this so as to only sum the quantity for certain manifest objects. For example do the same as above but only where manifests.reference = 10? I've edited my question above to include the reference field in the Manifests model.

Comment: Thank you for your help!